# Close popup once click on close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Background** :

1.User click on **Mask** & upload their own image on the mask....

2.Once image uploaded, Edit Text is displaying on image....

3.Once user click on Edit Text, we are displaying pop up box....

4.Inside Popup box, we are displaying text **Content** & button **Close**

Once we click on "**close**" , its closing the pop up box....

```
$("<div id=\'dark" + newImageLoadedId + "\' class=\'dark_content\'>" +  
    "content" +
      "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"document.getElementById(\'dark" + newImageLoadedId + "\').style.display=\'none\'\">Close</a>" + "</div>").appendTo(".pip" + newImageLoadedId).css({
      "left": $('.edit' + newImageLoadedId).width() + 2 + "px",
      "top": "0px"
    });
```

[Codepen1](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/QPqzzJ)

Instead of keeping "content" , i replaced 2nd line in above code as below using **template tag**:

**script**

```
$("<div id=\'dark" + newImageLoadedId + "\' class=\'dark_content\'>" +  
    $('#demoTemplate').html() +
      "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"document.getElementById(\'dark" + newImageLoadedId + "\').style.display=\'none\'\">Close</a>" + "</div>").appendTo(".pip" + newImageLoadedId).css({
      "left": $('.edit' + newImageLoadedId).width() + 2 + "px",
      "top": "0px"
    });
```

**html**

```
<template id='demoTemplate'>
   <span class="pip">      
         <div class="btn-group" >
            content
         </div>                              
   </span>
</template>
```

**Issue** :

Now Close button is not clickable....

[Codepen2](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/yrzGxw)

**code snippet** :

```js
// Display pop up next to text
function closePopUp(el) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
    openID = null
}

function openPopUp(el) {
    ///console.log(" open is called ",id)
    if (openID != null) {
        closePopUp(openID)
    }
    el.style.display = 'block';
    openID = el;
}


let openID = null;


var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {
  "path" : " newyear collage\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : "",
    "keywords" : "",
    "file" : "newyear collage",
    "date" : "sRGB",
    "title" : "",
    "description" : "Normal",
    "generator" : "Export Kit v1.2.8"
  },
  "name" : "newyear collage",
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 612,
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "height" : 612,
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 612,
          "shapeType" : "rectangle",
          "type" : "shape",
          "name" : "bg_rectangle"
        },
        {
          "x" : 160,
          "height" : 296,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 296,
              "src" : "ax0HVTs.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 429,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 188,
              "y" : 122,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 291,
          "width" : 429,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 25,
          "height" : 324,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 324,
              "src" : "hEM2kEP.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 471,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_2"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 209,
              "y" : 136,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse_2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 22,
          "width" : 471,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0,
      "width" : 612,
      "type" : "group",
      "name" : "newyearcollage08"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    // below code will upload image onclick mask image

    $('.container').click(function(e) {
        // filtering out non-canvas clicks
        if (e.target.tagName !== 'CANVAS') return;

        // getting absolute points relative to container
        const absX = e.offsetX + e.target.parentNode.offsetLeft + e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
        const absY = e.offsetY + e.target.parentNode.offsetTop + e.currentTarget.offsetTop;

        const $canvasList = $(this).find('canvas');
        // moving all canvas parents on the same z-index
        $canvasList.parent().css({
            zIndex: 0
        });

        $canvasList.filter(function() { // filtering only applicable canvases
            const bbox = this.getBoundingClientRect();
            const canvasTop = bbox.top + window.scrollY;
            const canvasLeft = bbox.left + window.scrollX;
            return (
                absX >= canvasLeft && absX <= canvasLeft + bbox.width &&
                absY >= canvasTop && absY <= canvasTop + bbox.height)
        }).each(function() { // checking white in a click position
            const x = absX - this.parentNode.offsetLeft - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
            const y = absY - this.parentNode.offsetTop - e.currentTarget.offsetTop;
            const pixel = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                $(this).parent().css({
                    zIndex: 2
                })
                target = this.id;
                console.log(target);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        })
    });

    // Below code will fetch mask images from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {
            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

            //Get Height and width of mask image [ edit button ]
            var ImagePosition = arr;
            //code end

            // Display icon only for mask images

            if (name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1) {
                var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;
            } else {
                var imageUrl1 = '';
            }
            //code end

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl1,
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";

                    //  Edit image

if ($(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).length === 1) 
{
    $("<span class=\"pip pip" + newImageLoadedId + "\">" +
        "<a onclick='document.getElementById(\"dark" + newImageLoadedId + "\").style.display=\"block\";'><span class=\"edit edit" + newImageLoadedId + "\" >Edit </span></a>" +
    "</span>").insertAfter(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).css({
        "left": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].x + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].width / 2) + "px",
        "top": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].y + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].height / 2) + "px"
    });
 
 $("<div id=\'dark" + newImageLoadedId + "\' class=\'dark_content\'>" + 
 $('#demoTemplate').html() +
      "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"document.getElementById(\'dark" + newImageLoadedId + "\').style.display=\'none\'\">Close</a>" + "</div>").appendTo(".pip" + newImageLoadedId).css({
      "left": $('.edit' + newImageLoadedId).width() + 2 + "px",
      "top": "0px"
    });
 
 
}                   
                    // Edit code end here....        
                    //  Remove image

$("<br/><span id=\"" + newImageLoadedId + "\" class=\"remove\">Remove</span>").insertAfter(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).css({
    "left": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].x + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].width / 2) + "px",
    "top": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].y + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].height / 2 +25) + "px"
});    

                $(".remove").click(function(event) {
                    const canvasId = "canvas#" + event.currentTarget.id;
                    // Delete the image
                    const ctx = $("canvas")[event.currentTarget.id].getContext("2d");
                    ctx.fillStyle = "white"
                    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500)
                    // Delete the Remove button
     $(this).next().find('.edit').remove()
                    $(this).remove();
     
                });

                  // Remove image code end here.... 
            };
            counter++;
        }
        drawText(data);
    }
    json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

const fonts = []; // caching duplicate fonts

function drawText(layer) {

    if (layer.type === 'image') return;

    if (!layer.type || layer.type === 'group') {
        return layer.layers.forEach(drawText)
    }

    if (layer.type === 'text') {
        const url = 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + layer.src;

        if (!fonts.includes(url)) {
            fonts.push(url);
            $("style").prepend("@font-face {\n" +
                "\tfont-family: \"" + layer.font + "\";\n" +
                "\tsrc: url(" + url + ") format('truetype');\n" +
                "}");
        }

        // Below is POP UP Code
        const lightId = 'light' + layer.name
        const lightIdString = '#' + lightId
        $('.container').append(
            '<a id ="' + layer.name + '" onclick="openPopUp(' + lightId + ')"' +
            '<div class="txtContainer" contenteditable="true" ' +
            'style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +
            'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' +
            '">' + layer.text + '</div></a>' +
            '<div id="light' + layer.name + '" class="white_content" style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' + '"> content <a href="javascript:void(0)" ' +
            'onclick="closePopUp(' + lightId + ')">Close</a></div> <div>'
        );
        document.getElementById(lightId).style.left = layer.x + document.getElementById(layer.name).offsetWidth + 'px'
        // Above is POP UP Code
    }

}
// extempl code end 



// jq plugin 

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }


        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;

                $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
                container.selected(evt);
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                var img = new Image();
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');

            }
        };

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {

            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
                if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                    if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                        var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                        var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                        if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                            return; // position has not changed
                        settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                        settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                        prevX = evt.clientX;
                        prevY = evt.clientY;
                        clearTimeout(timeout);
                        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                            container.updateStyle();
                            renderInnerImage();
                        }, 20);
                    }
                } else {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };

        function renderInnerImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            img.src = settings.imageUrl;
            img.onload = function() {
                settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                initImage = false;
            };
        }

        // change the draggable image

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("load");
            //if (img)
            // img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle().then(renderInnerImage);
            // sirpepole  Add this
            return settings.id;
        };


        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        // Edit image
        div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
        // code end
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
 background: gold;
 position: relative;
}

.container img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 250px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.txtContainer {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFF
}

.txtContainer:hover {
 background: red;
 padding: 1px;
 border-style: dotted;
}

.pip {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.remove { 
 background: #444;
 border: 1px solid black;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 3;
}

.remove:hover {
 background: white;
 color: black;
}

.edit {
 display: block;
 background: #444;
 border: 1px solid black;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 3;
}

.edit:hover {
 background: white;
 color: black;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 3;
}

.white_content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 left: 25%;
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 padding: 16px;
 border: 16px solid orange;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 1002;
 overflow: auto;
}

.dark_content {
 display: none;
 position: relative;
 top: 25%;
 left: 25%;
 width: 350px;
 height: 350px;
 padding: 16px;
 border: 16px solid orange;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 1002;
 overflow: auto;
}

.btn-group 
{ 
position:relative; left:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container">

</div>

<template id='demoTemplate'>
   <span class="pip">
      
         <div class="btn-group" >
            content
         </div>                 
     
   </span>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove your close buttons class its works. So maybe there is a problem in css.

Answer (score 1):

common pitfall, your click events are not fired because you bound them to elements that were not there on script runtime, e.g you are doing dom-manipulation later on.

Quick solution, bind your click events to some element thats there from the begin on e.g `document`

so for example change

```
$(".remove").click(function(event) { ...
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(event){ ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated code that you posted in answer , but still the same result.... here is https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/bJoyay

Comment: hmn feels bad man, maybe you should try to continue replacing all click handlers in the style above, i mean also use a class and data attribute instead of spawning elements with onclick, this seems pretty unconsistent to me using vanilla here, html-attributes there and some jquery in between to handle clicks